# How can I display the checkbox over the images for selection?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a checkbox for selection on the right bottom of every image..

How can i do something like this?

Please remember that clicking on image has a unique event(that i'll manage to do!) , but clicking on that check box should select/deselect that one?

Comment: i think correct way to work on this can be, by taking a `div` and place `back-ground images` to it and inside each `div` you can have checkboxes..

Comment: That's what i thought also, but i dont know how do it using css (i.e how to construct html for this)! Can anyone provide html/css for displaying a single picture of this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can be done with pure CSS, assuming you have fixed width and height for all images. The trick is setting absolute position for the checkbox then assign `bottom` and `right` to zero.

HTML sample:

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="image1.jpg" /> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check1" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="image2.jpg" />
    <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox" id="check2" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container { position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin-left: 10px; }
.checkbox { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; }
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/erSBP/1/).

As for click events, just apply click handler to each checkbox and it will work just fine.. see in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erSBP/2/).

Answer (score 11):

[image]

You can use a **"label"** tag that contains an **"img"** tag inside.

Here's an example of using an image as a checkbox and radio.

```css
* {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --transition: 0.15s;
  --border-radius: 0.5rem;
  --background: #ffc107;
  --box-shadow: #ffc107;
}

.cont-bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle farthest-corner at 7.2% 13.6%,
    rgba(37, 249, 245, 1) 0%,
    rgba(8, 70, 218, 1) 90%
  );
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.cont-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-checkbox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  background: white;
  transition: transform var(--transition);
}

.cont-checkbox:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
}

.cont-checkbox:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--background);
}

input:checked + label img {
  -webkit-filter: none; /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: none;
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

label img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 81%, 50% 100%, 0 81%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

label .cover-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--box-shadow);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: transform var(--transition),
    opacity calc(var(--transition) * 1.2) linear;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label .cover-checkbox svg {
  width: 13px;
  height: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  fill: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 3px;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.4s ease var(--transition);
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
}

label .info {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-bg">
  <div class="cont-title">Checkbox</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-1" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-2" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont-title">Radio</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-1" />
      <label for="myRadio-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-2" />
      <label for="myRadio-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If only selecting/deselecting of the checkbox is your requirement then what I would suggest is :

**Step 1:** Place the image and the checkbox inside a block (may it be a div or table)

**Step 2:** Provide that block relative position with some specific height and width.

**Step 3:** For checkbox, give it absolute position and set the right and bottom gaps (based on your requirement).

For instance, the code should look like this

```html
<div class="img_block">
  <img src="image-path" alt="" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" />
</div>
<div class="img_block">
  <img src="image-path" alt="" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" />
</div>
```

And the **css** for the same is

```css
.img_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.chkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 3px;
}
```

I hope this suits your requirement.

Answer (score -2):

If it were me I would try usign jQuery for this.Lets pretend that each image is in each own div and the checkbo has an id of check:

```
  $('div').click(function()

    { 
         //you select the checkbox and ad the code to do what you want to it

       ('#check').

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean to say? Incomplete answer. The question is about showing a checkbox over image.