# Checkbox inside image in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi guys is there a way to put the checkbox inside the image?. Currently it is still on the left side of the image. Thank you.

**HTML:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in xt">

                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="x.is_valid" ng-model="xlist.isChecked[x.id]"/>
                <img src="{{x.picture}} " onerror="this.src='/images/default_pic.jpg'" ><br>
  </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display the checkbox over the images for selection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877807/how-can-i-display-the-checkbox-over-the-images-for-selection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar question asked here: [How can I display the checkbox over the images for selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877807/how-can-i-display-the-checkbox-over-the-images-for-selection) 
 where the answer uses css with the correct positioning.

GL!