# How to Tick a checkbox on Clicking an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was able to create the code for it, but the checkbox doesn't appear above the image. It's slightly displaced, how do i fix it?

```css
.custom-checkbox input {
  display: none;
}

.custom-checkbox span {
  border: 2px solid #7e8a94;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.custom-checkbox:hover span,
.custom-checkbox input:checked + span {
  border: 3px solid #43D8B0;
}

.custom-checkbox input:checked + span:before {
  content: "✔";
}
```

```html
 <label class="custom-checkbox">
    
 <img class="img" src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2rrqs1l.png"/>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span></span>
</label>
```

I want the checkbox to appear on the top left side,
This way: http://prntscr.com/j960yk

Thanks for your time.

Comment: where do you suggest i shud upload it?

Comment: the question title doesn't describe what you are asking for in the question details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use images like checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663562/use-images-like-checkboxes)

Comment: sorry let me fix it, cuz i can see the image.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate of the previous question, i have already referred it, before posting this one.

Comment: Check this one https://jsfiddle.net/y88zLp2r/

Comment: I have Fixed the error..IMAGE IS NOW VISIBLE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added `float: left;` to your `.custom-checkbox span` CSS rule, added a `br` tag and modified your HTML a bit.

```css
.custom-checkbox input {
  display: none;
}

.custom-checkbox span {
  border: 2px solid #7e8a94;
  /* float: right; - you don't need that. Use float: left; */
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.custom-checkbox:hover span,
.custom-checkbox input:checked+span {
  border: 3px solid #43D8B0;
}

.custom-checkbox input:checked+span:before {
  content: "✔";
}
```

```html
<label class="custom-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
  <span></span>   
  <br>
  <br>
 <img class="img" src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2rrqs1l.png"/>
</label>
```

Comment: with float:left, it comes to the left hand side of the image (http://prntscr.com/j96aft), i want to show the checkbox on the TOP-left of the image.

Comment: can you please implement it with my image (http://i63.tinypic.com/2rrqs1l.png), with your image it appears properly, but with mine, it still displaces a bit. (http://prntscr.com/j96hnh)

Comment: even while trying it in stackoverflow, it still displaces (http://prntscr.com/j96ics).

Comment: @joe997 Even with your picture, it works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/tgm1mLaL/2/

Comment: YES, it works now, earlier it wasn't,. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <label class="custom-checkbox">

 <img class="img" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" width="300"/>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span></span>
</label>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('img').click(function() {
 $(this).find('checkbox').checked(true);
 })
});
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y88zLp2r/

Comment: It seems to me he had a problem with position of checkbox, not functionality

Comment: Yes, i was able to create this version of it, please refer to my version, i want the tick box in this fashion(http://prntscr.com/j960yk). Plus, i don't wish to use the basic checkbox, i prefer mine.

Comment: yes problem with POSITION of checkbox not functionality.

Answer (score 1):

just place the input before the image and remove the float right style.

```css
.custom-checkbox input {
  display: none;
}

.custom-checkbox span {
  border: 2px solid #7e8a94;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.custom-checkbox:hover span,
.custom-checkbox input:checked + span {
  border: 3px solid #43D8B0;
}

.custom-checkbox input:checked + span:before {
  content: "✔";
}
```

```html
<label class="custom-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox"/> 
  <span></span>
  <img class="img" src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2rrqs1l.png"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some more css

```
.custom-checkbox{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   padding-top: 30px;
 }
 .custom-checkbox span{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }
```

This will work

Comment: NOPE, this one appears ON the image, not above the image. (http://prntscr.com/j96di1)

Comment: set span top property to -30px i.e why i used top padding on label.

Comment: above solution works perfectly fine. check my second answer where I combined your and my code.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.custom-checkbox input {
  display: none;
}
.custom-checkbox{
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   padding-top: 30px;
 }

.custom-checkbox span {
  border: 2px solid #7e8a94;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.custom-checkbox:hover span,
.custom-checkbox input:checked + span {
  border: 3px solid #43D8B0;
}

.custom-checkbox input:checked + span:before {
  content: "✔";
}
```

```html
 <label class="custom-checkbox">
    
 <img class="img" src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2rrqs1l.png"/>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .custom-checkbox span {
     border: 2px solid #7e8a94;
     height: 20px;
     width: 20px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
```

Change html like this

```
<label class="custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span></span>
 <img class="img" src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2rrqs1l.png">
</label>
```

Comment: the checkbox in this case shows ON the image (http://prntscr.com/j96cd8), i want it to be on the TOP LEFT corner of the image(http://prntscr.com/j960yk)

Comment: changed answer @joe997

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `for` attribute to your label, and assigning it the same value as the `name` attribute for the checkbox, the label will work as a clickable extension of your checkbox.

This way, you can place the label wherever you want in the layout. Like so:

```
<label for="image-checkbox" class="custom-checkbox">
    <img class="img" src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2rrqs1l.png"/>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="image-checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('ready',function(){
$("#avatar").on('click',function(){
$("#chkbox").trigger( "click" )

})

})
```

```css
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
    }

    .image {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .5s ease;
      background-color: #0000;
    }

    .container:hover .overlay {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    

    .text {
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar"  class="image">
      <div id="avatar" class="overlay">
        <div class="text"><input id="chkbox" type="checkbox"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use a **"label**" tag that contains an **"img"** tag inside.

I only use html and css.

I have the answer at this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395887/12569619