# Hide HTML checkbox, but keep function when using a custom image checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use images to create a custom checkbox. I know how to do this, and there are a lot of great alternatives on this site. But my number one goal here is learning so I would like to ask this question. 
When I hide the HTML checkbox with CSS using display: none; the jquery code doesn't work anymore. And that makes sense to me, but how can I make it so the custom checkbox with the images also functions like the original one?

HTML

```
<div id="togglecontainer">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox'+(counter)+'"class="item"/>
    <label for="checkbox"></label>
    <input value="make me bold" type="text" class="inputfield"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inputfield{
    padding-left: 20px;
}

label:before {
    content: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/unchecked_checkbox.png");
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
    content:url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/checked_checkbox.png");
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    //display: none; 
}

.complete { 
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
    background-color:transparent;
    border: 0px solid;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color:#222222;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#togglecontainer").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "change", function () {
    $(this).nextAll().toggleClass("complete");
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8t25f6mp/)

P.s. A little side question; as you can see this fiddle uses an older version of jQuery. When I link to a newer version the whole thing doesn't work anymore. Can someone elaborate on that a little as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use visibility:none instead of display:none.... as visibility:hidden will make that the element is available on DOM and it is hidden

Comment: as far as i know delegate is deprecated, use "on" instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always wrap the checkbox inside the label and then not need the `id` or the `for`.

My example does not use images. I don't need `id` or `for` and if you click on the text it also works.

I did make the text into just text and no longer an `<input type="text">` field.

I also re-wrote the code in vanilla JS and not using jQuery. This will still work with jQuery in the rest of your code, bit it will also work without jQuery.

```js
var el = document.querySelector("#togglecontainer");
el.addEventListener("change", evt => {
  if (evt.target.type === "checkbox") {
    evt.target.parentNode.classList.toggle("checked", evt.target.checked);
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
.my-checkbox:before {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-checkbox.checked {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.my-checkbox.checked:before {
  content: '✓';
}

.my-checkbox [type=checkbox] {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="togglecontainer">
  <label class="my-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    make me bold
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use a **"label**" tag that contains an **"img"** tag inside.

I have the answer at this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395887/12569619

Answer (score 0):

use opacity:0; instead of display:none; the checkbox will still be there and you can click on it but you can't see it

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong id attribute in checkbox so clicking in label is not calling change in checkbox.

Just try maching "for" attribute in label with "id" attribute in input (checkbox).

```js
 $("#togglecontainer").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "change", function () {
        $(this).nextAll().toggleClass("complete");
    });
```

```css
.inputfield{
padding-left: 20px;


}
label:before {
  content: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/unchecked_checkbox.png");
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  content: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/checked_checkbox.png");
}

input[type=checkbox] {

}

.complete { 
font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
background-color:transparent;
border: 0px solid;
margin-left: 20px;
color:#222222;
font-style:oblique;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="togglecontainer">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="item" style="display: none"/>
<label for="checkbox"></label>
<input value="make me bold" type="text" class="inputfield"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. The thing is,... I do need the counter for the ID's because of another function. Because the checkboxes will be generated with an append button. Sorry for not pointing that out.

Comment: There's no way that this will work - `id="checkbox'+(counter)+'"`.